# Media Manager selectection state does not have thumbnail size

Tags: media-modal

I have written a plugin that uses the new media manager UI to insert images into a custom gallery custom post type. Everything works 100% but on a specific user's site something strange is happending that I cannot reproduce locally. Here is the code:

```
    var attachments = FOOGALLERY.media_uploader.state().get('selection').toJSON();

    $.each(attachments, function(i, item) {
      if (item && item.id && item.sizes && item.sizes.thumbnail) {
        var attachment = {
            id: item.id,
            src: item.sizes.thumbnail.url
        };

        FOOGALLERY.addAttachmentToGalleryList(attachment);
    } else {
        //there was a problem adding the item! Move on to the next
    }
```

As you can see on line 3, it does a check if the item is valid before it adds the thumb to the gallery.

`item.sizes` has data, but it only contains `full` but I rely on it having `thumbnail` to insert the thumb. Basically, `item.sizes.thumbnail` is return false so it never adds the image to the gallery.

So my question is "Why no thumbnail, dude?"

I checked his media settings and he does have thumbnails set at 200x200. The media library itself is showing his thumbnail images in the modal too.

As I said, I cannot reproduce this locally no matter what I try, and my `items.sizes` always contains `thumbnail`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that if the default images sizes have been changed, then there will be an instance when the `item.sizes.thumbnail` will be underfined.

I ended up building in a check for this and if thumbnail was not defined, then I use the original image instead